# Angular SSR double loading on client

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have an angular 7.2.16 application and due to SEO reason I installed angular SSR as described in https://angular.io/guide/universal. When I load the application I noticed that it's loaded twice, i.e. on the client I have an html version at the beginning and when the javascript is executed on the client then it shows a loader re-brings everything.

I checked [link](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/transfer-http.md), I installed and I still have the same issue. The way I have implemented it doesn't make sense that this solution is going to work. For instance:

```
  ngOnInit()  {

    this.myItems = []
    this.spinner.show();
    this.httpClient.post(myurl).subscribe((val) => {
        this.myItems = val; // it has images that are shown on html through ngFor

        // add some og: metadata

        this.spinner.hide();
      }, (err) => {

         this.spinner.hide();
    });
  }
```

On the client I get the full html version at the beginning...Due to TransferHttpCacheModule  the httpClient is intercepted so it will not call it again. Since I don't have any condition that I'm on the client or server side it seems that it's going to be executed twice, which what it happens.

What I have to solve are:
1. On the server having proper og meta tags
2. On the client do not show something that has already been loaded on the server, or do not show any content when I'm on client.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, it's not very clear. `TransferHttpCacheModule` will prevent client side API calls for when the page is displayed; once you start navigating it won't work anymore. And point #2 is not very clear. Use `isPlatformBrowser` checks to choose wether to display data or not depending on wether the app is runnin server or client side.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching and with the help of @David this was the solution:

```
import {Inject, Injectable, PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

...

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private _platformId: Object){}

  ngOnInit()  {

    this.myItems = []
    this.spinner.show();
    this.httpClient.post(myurl).subscribe((val) => {

        if (isPlatformBrowser(this._platformId)) {
            this.myItems = val; // it has images that are shown on html through ngFor
        }
        // add some og: metadata

        this.spinner.hide();
      }, (err) => {

         this.spinner.hide();
    });
  }
```